# Copy Text to Clipboard in Delphi TMS Web Core Website

Tags: string, delphi, text, clipboard, tms-web-core

The VCL/FMX way of copying text to the clipboard doesn't work in TMS Web Core.

How can I copy text (Strings) to the clipboard in a Delphi TMS Web Core Website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are multiple ways to copy text to the clipboard in TMS Web Core:

---

## 1. TWebClipboard (Non-Visual Component)

[image: Delphi TWebClipboard]

Add a `TWebClipboard` component to your form and then you can copy text to it by running:

```
WebClipboard.CopyToClipboard('Your String to Copy to Clipboard');
```

---

## 2. TWebClipboard Custom Method

You can make your own procedure that creates and uses the `TWebClipboard` component from the `WEBLib.Clipboard` unit:

```
procedure CopyTextToClipboard(aText: String);
var
  WebClipboard: TWebClipboard;
begin
  WebClipboard := TWebClipboard.Create(self);
  try
    WebClipboard.CopyToClipboard(aText);
  finally
    WebClipboard.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

## 3. JavaScript function

You can make a Delphi function that uses JavaScript to copy text to the clipboard:

```
procedure CopyTextToClipboard(aText: String);
begin
  asm
    window.navigator.clipboard.writeText(aText);
  end;
end;
```