# Copy Image to Clipboard in a Delphi TMS WEB Core Website

Tags: image, delphi, clipboard, tms, tms-web-core

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77290150/2908017)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290151/2908017) is for copying text to a Clipboard in TMS WEB Core, but how do I copy an image to the Clipboard?

Let's say I have a `TWebImageControl` component on my form, how can I copy the image in it to my Clipboard from a button click?

Comment: Did you check the documentation or source for the TWebClipboard component to see if it has a method to do so (such as an overloaded CopyToClipboard metnod)?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, but it wasn't useful. I couldn't get the image copied to my clipboard. Here's the link to the documentation: https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/twebclipboard/

Comment: First let me ask you something. When copying this image into clipboard do you intent to use this copied data within your own program or also with other programs? Why am I asking this? Well copying data to clipboard is just a first step in sharing this data with some other application. Second step is for this other application to paste the data. And in order to do so it needs to support the data type with which the data was stored in clipboard. When installed many desktop applications actually registers their own custom clipboard formats

Comment: You should read more about [Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats) in order to have better understanding of how this all works.

Comment: @SilverWarior Within other programs also. Users should be able to paste it into other programs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321606/copy-image-to-clipboard-from-browser-in-javascript

Comment: @JohnEasley Is there not a Delphi way of doing it? Preferably I'd like to do it with some kind of Delphi way instead of just using JavaScript. maybe somehow with TWebClipboard if possible.

Comment: Do you want to copy/paste into another WebImageControl or just copy the image to the clipboard?

Comment: @JohnEasley Just to the Clipboard

Comment: You can right-click and copy an image, so I'm assuming you want to do something with it.. that's the trickier part and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @JohnEasley I want to copy it to the Clipboard via a button click